# Hash tables - Perfect hashing

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I want to create a hash table with perfect hashing for a dictionary. The thing is I still don't quite get it. What I understand is that you have two universal function h1 and h2. Then you map the keys to a table with h1, and then you create a new table for every slot in the first table.

That's all good. The thing is:
1) h1 is a function that picks a random vector 'a' = {a1,a2,...,an}, then you dot-product this with the key(which is also a vector).
Question 1:
Let's say I have a String as my key, how would I pick vector 'a', and how would I pick the key?

Question 2:
Supposedly if h2 collides, you pick another h2 from the same family of functions. But then how would I find it when I search for it? I would have to go through the same process again?

If someone decides to help me, examples (they don't have to be complex) would be very appreciated.

Comment: Consider narrowing this down to a single question--you're all over the place, and it doesn't look like you've attempted much of anything yet based on what you've said. In addition, this appears to be more of a theory question than a software development question. By narrowing it down to one question and explaining anything you do understand, that appearance should improve and be more on-topic.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/